# Script that's run from processing is not executing properly

Tags: java, bash, shell, processing

I have a shell script that creates a text file that contains the current settings from my camera:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="test.txt"
[[ -f "$file" ]] && rm -f "$file"

var=$(gphoto2 --summary)
echo "$var" >> "test.txt" 


if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Successfully created file"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Could not create file" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The script works as I think it should when I run it from terminal, but when I run the following processing app the text file is created but does not contain any of the information from the camera:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

void setup() {
    size(480, 120);
    camSummary();
}

void draw() {
}
void camSummary() {
    String commandToRun = "./ex2.sh"; 
    File workingDir = new File("/Users/loren/Documents/RC/CamSoft/");
    String returnedValues;    // value to return any results 


    try {
        println("in try");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun, null, workingDir);
        int i = p.waitFor();
        if (i==0) {
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ( (returnedValues = stdInput.readLine ()) != null) {
            println(returnedValues);
            }
       } else{
            println("i is:  " + i); 
       }
   }
   catch(Throwable t) {
       println(t);
   }
}
```

Eventually I would like to read some of the data directly from the script into variables and then use those variables in processing.

Could someone help me sort this out?

Thank you,

Loren

Alternate script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
exec 2>&1

file="test.txt"
[ -f "$file" ] && rm -f "$file"


# you want to store the output of gphoto2 in a variable
# var=$(gphoto2 --summary)
# problem 1: what if PATH environment variable is wrong (i.e. gphoto2 not accessible)?
# problem 2: what if gphoto2 outputs to stderr?
# it's better first to:

echo first if
if ! type gphoto2 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "gphoto2 not found!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo second if
# Why using var?...
gphoto2 --summary > "$file" 2>&1
# if you insert any echo here, you will alter $?
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Successfully created file"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Could not create file" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps `/bin/sh` is not the same as `/bin/bash`, and `sh` does not know how to do `$()`. Try `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I tried both sh and bash... no change

Comment: I don't know if this matters or not but gphoto2 is a command line application.   The argument --summery gets me a bunch ov values.

Comment: Is your processing running under the same login id? Try adding `set -x` and `exec 2>&1` to the start of the shell script.

Comment: @meuh thanks for the tip.  The commands that you had me set echoed the output back to processing.  When you run the script from processing the console says gphoto2: command not found.  I'm running this on a mac with my login, so I assume that all of the commands are using my credentials right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your shell script. Let's correct and improve it together.

```
#!/bin/sh

file="test.txt"
[ -f "$file" ] && rm -f "$file"

# you want to store the output of gphoto2 in a variable
# var=$(gphoto2 --summary)
# problem 1: what if PATH environment variable is wrong (i.e. gphoto2 not accessible)?
# problem 2: what if gphoto2 outputs to stderr?
# it's better first to:
if ! type gphoto2 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "gphoto2 not found!" >&2
    exit 1
fi
# Why using var?...
gphoto2 --summary > "$file" 2>&1
# if you insert any echo here, you will alter $?
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Successfully created file"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Could not create file" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I need to do a little digging to completely understand but what you recommend seems to make sense.  When this is run from the terminal it works like it should.  When I run it from processing the exit doesn't return it simply returns "done"....weird

Comment: I stand corrected.  The "done" came from something else I added to further troubleshoot this morning.  This didn't work either

Comment: If the corrected shell script does not work, you must debug the issue in the java domain.

Comment: In the alternate script you can see in the OP I've added the script suggested in this answer, @meuh suggested I added set -x
exec 2>&1 which I did, and for the original code it provided some console output to processing to help me figure out what issues are going on.  When I run this suggested script with those two lines I get nothing.  Any suggestions as to how I can debug the java further in the processing IDE?

Comment: In your terminal run `type -p gphoto2`. It will return the absolute path of `gphoto2`. Now, in the shell script replace the `gphoto2` calls with the path got from `type -p gphoto2`.